# Magento not sending order emails despite cron being set up correctly

Tags: email, cron

Having some real trouble getting my Magento installation to send out order emails.

Before you say it, I've set up a cron, and yes it's running (I've even tested it with a basic php echo to be sure).

I've currently got the cron set up as

```
 /usr/bin/php -f /home/username/public_html/cron.php
```

But I've also tried

```
www-data /bin/sh /home/username/cron.sh cron.php -m=always
php -f /home/username/public_html/cron.php
```

All scheduled between 1 and 15 minutes per cycle.

I've also set up the AOE scheduler AND ran the core_email_queue_send_all task and all emails send as expected. On the AOE, I get a heartbeat task error, but then again I have the same on another site where I'm having no issue.

Could this be a server thing? I believe the IT guy changed some permissions to allow me shell access, but I can't see why that would be a problem.

Thanks in advance.